# filter a regex result from a get-content command

Tags: regex, powershell

i have a text file which have on each line a sentence of this form:

`XXXX - hi
XXXX - hello
XXXX - whatever
WW - blabla
WW - blblbl
CCC - nice
CCC - common
CCC - itsux
CCC - regex
BBBB_BBB - flibidibalala`

what i'm trying to do is to create a regex with powershell to sort this content like this:

`XXXX
WW
CCC
BBBB_BB`

I want to sort the first file lines to have only one time the part before the " -".
I've tried somethings like this:

`Get-Content coucou2.txt  -Filter '(\w - )?'`

`Get-Content coucou2.txt  -Filter '\w - ?'`

`Get-Content coucou2.txt  -Filter '\w - {1}'`

`Get-Content coucou2.txt  -Filter '(\w - ){1}'`

`Get-Content coucou2.txt  | Select-String '\w - {1}'`

`Get-Content coucou2.txt  | Select-String '(\w - ){1}'`

`Get-Content coucou2.txt  | Select-String '(\w - )?'`

`Get-Content coucou2.txt  | Select-String '\w - ?'`

But none of them worked,
Is someone have an idea or just a clue to help me please ?

Comment: I can't figure out exactly what you want from your description. Can you post the end result you'd expect?

Comment: i want to display only one time the part before the " -", my real file is the result of a query on AD division, there is a lot of groups and they have the same type of names 'type of group - group'.
Like this: XXX - group1; XXX - group2; BBB - group1; CCC - group1 etc
I would like to sort the types of groups by displaying only one time the part before the " -" like in my example: XXX, BBB, CCC even if there is mutliple lines which are beginning by XXX BBB or CCC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping your groups might be more interesting:

```
> Get-Content .\coucou2.txt|Group-Object {($_ -split ' ')[0]}

Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    3 XXXX                      {XXXX - hi, XXXX - hello, XXXX - whatever}
    2 WW                        {WW - blabla, WW - blblbl}
    4 CCC                       {CCC - nice, CCC - common, CCC - itsux, CCC - regex}
    1 BBBB_BBB                  {BBBB_BBB - flibidibalala}
```

---

```
> Get-Content .\coucou2.txt|Group-Object {($_ -split ' ')[0]} -NoElement

Count Name
----- ----
    3 XXXX
    2 WW
    4 CCC
    1 BBBB_BBB
```

---

```
> (Get-Content .\coucou2.txt|Group-Object {($_ -split ' ')[0]} -NoElement).Name
XXXX
WW
CCC
BBBB_BBB
```

Answer (score 2):

The following solution using `-Split` will suffice.

```
# sort.txt file contains the strings in your example randomized
Get-Content sort.txt

WW - blblbl
CCC - nice
CCC - itsux
CCC - regex
BBBB_BBB - flibidibalala
XXXX - whatever
WW - blabla
CCC - common
XXXX - hello
XXXX - hi

# Code to sort and output sorted strings
Get-Content sort.txt | ForEach-Object {
  ($_ -split " - ")[0]} | Sort-Object -Desc -Unique

XXXX
WW
CCC
BBBB_BBB
```

The method above splits (`-split`) each line (one at a time) delimiting by `-` and then grabs the first item (`[0]`) from the resulting split. The pipe into `Sort-Object` sorts in descending order (`-Desc`) and outputs only unique objects (`-Unique`) <sub>(cudo's [Lieven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52598/lieven-keersmaekers))</sub>. You could also use `Group-Object` here to grab the `.name` property, which will output the unique strings. See [about_Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-6) and [Sort-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-6). Also, see [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-6).

If you are dead set on regex, you can use the -replace operator, but this includes duplicates:

```
(Get-Content sort.txt) -Replace "(\w+) - .*",'$1' | Sort-Object -Desc

XXXX
XXXX
XXXX
XX
WW
WW
CCC
CCC
CCC
CCC
BBBB_BBB
BB
```

Using the same method as above displaying no duplicates:

```
(Get-Content sort.txt) -Replace "(\w+) - .*",'$1' | Sort-Object -Desc -Unique

XXXX
XX
WW
CCC
BBBB_BBB
BB
```

See [About Comparison Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6) to find more information on `-Replace`.

Comment: Yes exactly, the first regex worked like i wanted ! thanks a lot

Comment: Why not `Sort-Object -Unique`?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, I am going to update the code to use that if that's okay with you.

Comment: @AdminOfThings - no problem but now it looks like I contributed half the script. I've edited a minor bit to reflect the real contribution a bit better (less ;))